# Why setInexactRepeating in alarm manager trigger inappropriately

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

This is strange, what is the reason method setInexactRepeating trigger approximately at given time rather then exact time.

I need to trigger alarm on every day basis at one particular time, i have said

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
// Set the alarm's trigger time to 8:30 a.m.
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  
calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

I have set time 8:30 am in the calendar, when i shift device day to next day, alarm get trigger immediately even before i shift device time to 8:30am.

What is happening here, why i can't make exact trigger using this api, if any of you have experience this, could you share your experience. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike, it is "setInexactRepeating "

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't consider the possible language barrier. "Inexact" means "not exact". If you want an exact, repeating alarm (since KitKat), you need to use a `setExact*()` method, and set the alarm again each time it fires.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation ([here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)) there is text:

> As described above, choosing the alarm type is often the first step in
> creating an alarm. A further distinction is how precise you need your
> alarm to be. For most apps, setInexactRepeating() is the right choice.
> When you use this method, Android synchronizes multiple inexact
> repeating alarms and fires them at the same time. This reduces the
> drain on the battery.
>
> **For the rare app that has rigid time requirements—for example, the
> alarm needs to fire precisely at 8:30 a.m., and every hour on the hour
> thereafter—use setRepeating().** But you should avoid using exact alarms
> if possible.
>
> **With setInexactRepeating(), you can't specify a custom interval the
> way you can with setRepeating()**. You have to use one of the interval
> constants, such as INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_DAY, and so on.

I hope it could help You bit. There is also small example for it in previous link I gave You.